# Listing on a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks some what like this

[image]

As you can see I have rows having same Account Name but the rest of the columns are different
I want to list the entire record `having count(AccName) > 1`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, AccName, User, country, zip
from your_table
where AccName in (select AccName
    from your_table
    group by AccName
    having count(*) > 1)
```